# cuda compute wrong result in multiply counters

Tags: cuda

i am writing a code in cuda to try learning some concepts , here is the problem :

in line **@@@** if i use **(i*i)** it works well and result of multiply is true . but when i'm putting **(i*j)** counter , instead of **(i*i)** it produce wrong results. i think it may be my fault to set wrong **dimgrid & dimblock** or something else !!! any idea how to solve the problem ?
i put the c++ version at the end of my code to compare results.
thank you for your advise.

Here is my code :

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "time.h"

double diffclock(clock_t clock1,clock_t clock2) 
{
double diffticks=clock1-clock2;
double diffms=(diffticks*10)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
return diffms;
} 

using namespace std;
__global__ void add( int *c)
{

int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
int k = threadIdx.z + blockIdx.z * blockDim.z;
int nx,ny,nz;
nx = 512;
ny = 512 ;
nz = 51200 ;
if ((i < nx) && (j < ny) && (k < nz))
{

    *c = i*i; // **@@@**

}
}

int main()
{
printf("****************************************************************\n");
printf("                  CUDA_C COMPARISONE MODEL                          \n");
printf("\n");
printf("\n");
printf("this program will produce 512 * 512 * 51,200 for loop iteration \n");
printf("you can compare time elapsed between c++ version & cuda version \n");
printf("\n");
printf("\n");

printf("\n");
printf("****************************************************************\n");
cudaEvent_t beginEvent;
cudaEvent_t endEvent;
cudaEventCreate( &beginEvent );
cudaEventCreate( &endEvent );
int c;
int *dev_c;
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, sizeof(int));
dim3 dimgrid (16 , 16);
dim3 dimblock(32 , 32);
cudaEventRecord( beginEvent, 0 );
add<<<dimgrid,dimblock>>>(dev_c);
cudaMemcpy(&c, dev_c, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaEventRecord( endEvent, 0 );
cudaEventSynchronize( endEvent );
float timeValue;
cudaEventElapsedTime( &timeValue, beginEvent, endEvent );
printf( "Time elapsed in G-p-u : %f  ms \n" ,timeValue );
printf("_____________________________________________________\n");
printf("G-p-u multiply computation is =====>>> %d\n", c);
printf("_____________________________________________________\n");


// c++  code :

int n1 = 512 ;
int n2 = 512 ;
int n3 = 51200;

clock_t begin=clock();

int cp , ii,jj,kk;
for(kk=0; kk<n3; kk++)
  for(ii=0; ii<n2; ii++)
    for(jj=0; jj<n1; jj++)
         cp = (ii)*(jj);

clock_t end=clock();
cout << "Time elapsed in C-p-u : " << double(diffclock(end,begin)) << " ms"<< endl;
printf("_____________________________________________________\n");
printf("_____________________________________________________\n");

printf("C-p-u multiply computation is =====>>> %d\n", cp);
cudaFree(dev_c);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _correct_ result? You are passing a single element to your kernel function with a significant race condition issue.

Comment: @JackOLantern hi . i mean when i do multiplication in c version it do the multiply , and produce the true product number , but when do it again on the gpu with i*j tag the result of multiply is different . if the code i've written is true , the results must be the same , but why they aren't so ?

Comment: Again, what do you expect to be the _correct_ result in both the cases of `*c = i*i` and `*c = i*j`?

Comment: @JackOLantern hi, thank you for your attention . when i do i*j in C version code , every time it produce 261121 as the result of product , but in cuda kernel the product of i*j every time after compile makes different numbers which none of them are the same.this is what made me confused !!! i'll be sooo thankfull if you make this more clarify . why in my cuda code i*j doesn't produce the same number 261121 ???

Comment: Consider the fact that you are not storing your results in an array, as recommended by @RobertCrovella in his answer below, but you are only using a single memory location. So, in sequential programming, the value of `*c` is updated in an ordered way and what you are seeing is only the last update value, namely `261121`. In parallel programming, all the threads are _independently_ updating `*c` in an unordered way. To be more clear, imagine that you are asking a bunch of soldiers to execute an order, the update of `*c` in your case.

Comment: All the soldiers are trying to accomplish their task independently and without communicating each other. Some soldiers will be faster, some will be slower. What you will see after the command comes back to you is the update produced by the slowest soldier, which could not correspond to `261121`. Actually, by asking all the soldiers to access and update concurrently the same memory location is a bad mistake known as _race condition_. You will find a lot more material on race condition by a simple google search (search, for example, _race condition CUDA_).

Comment: @JackOLantern thank sooo much , now i exactly understand what you say. this example completely solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both CPU and GPU, you are running many calculations. You are comparing one calculation from the CPU to one calculation from the GPU. The problem is, you are not comparing the same calculation, so of course your results are different.  You are storing the results all in one location, one on top of the other. That won't work. The order of computation on the CPU is not the same as the order of computation on the GPU.

Store each calculation in a separate location, just as I have done [here](http://pastebin.com/XQKqhxnV).  Then when you compare results, you will be able to compare corresponding locations, and your results should then match.

Comment: hi , i read your link , but , i think that this doesn't solve the problem , because although the left side of your c[][][] array stores results on different locations in the memory but when i increase the dimension to 512*512*51200 the results corrupt !!! and again another question is what if i want to save results on none array variable ?you mean i have to use array to solve this ?